Can 3D convolutions appropriately capture a frozen embedding space?
My project is a strange combination of NLP and Computer Vision.
I have datapoints of 3D tensor where each element is a token in an NLP vocabulary. The vocabulary is around 1000 unique "words".
The tokens within the 3D tensor are spatially related to adjacent tokens. For this reason an embedding model is relevant. I'm using SkipGrams adapted to three dimensions (so instead of context windows, it's a context "cube" around a target token). Suppose I've pre-trained this SkipGram model on a whole dataset of these 3D tensors. Thus, I have a simple lookup table with which I can convert each token to its fixed embedding.
Now, I want to train a generative model on this dataset to capture it's distribution, and interpolate between points using a trained latent space. To do this, I'm using a Variational Auto Encoder architecture from Stable Diffusion adapted to three dimensions (Conv3D instead of Conv2D). To adapt it to three dimensions, I'm treating the embedding dimension as though it is a color channel in standard Conv3D implementations. Instead of taking a tensor of shape (3, Height, Width, Depth) as input, my VAE takes (Token Embedding Dimension Size, Height, Width, Depth) as input. The "3" in the standard Conv3D task corresponds to RGB values in a voxel image.
The question is: Will my VAE be able to capture the embedding dimension even though it is treated  as the "channel" dimension?
I've read some papers which suggest that the embedding space collapses if it is used as part of the training task for an instance like this, so I don't believe that is an option. Specifically, this paper found that "frozen embeddings alleviate the [embedding space] collapse remarkably"
